# Symfony NotFoundHttpException with route :80

Tags: symfony

Using Symfony 3.1, I am having problem with `NotFoundHttpException`.

facebook via  http://m.facebook.com requests route "`GET :80/...`", so I have added a specific route to redirect "`:80`" to the right route and it works when I request from the navigator (with and without a first slash), but I keep receiving errors and I don't know where to look (as log doesn't give any aditionnal data) and neither what to do.

The full error message is `request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET :80/..." (from "http://m.facebook.com")"`

Any idea ?

The Route is

```
/**
 * @Route(":80/...", name="redirect_80")
 * @Method({"GET", "HEAD"})
 */
public function shortLocaleRedirect80Action(Request $request)
{
    return $this->redirectToRoute(...);
}
```

[EDIT]

with the help of @Gerry, the problem may be a request like http://domain.name:80:80/... I know about sending a HttpNotFound when the request is bad (and that's what I do) but in this case the request is good except its ":80" part and it's preferable (for me) to be able to redirect these kind of requests to the right route. The problem is that I can't reproduce the request which make the error

[EDIT 2]

I can mostly insure that it comes from fb as I've shared on fb the page http://run.as/fr/pages/special-offer at 14:50 and received `request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET :80/fr/pages/special-offer" (from "http://m.facebook.com")"` at 15:51

Comment: Could you please elaborate with code and config samples what you did exactly?

Comment: So you're rewriting Facebook to Symfony... Good to know. Does Mark Zuckerberg know about it?

Comment: @Gerry, yes but what kind of code, it's just a simple route

Comment: It doesn't sound simple at all, you appear to be doing something very strange and I'm trying to understand what exactly it is.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: I don't do anything strange. I have a request for a Route from fb which I don't know where it comes from and try to just answer to this Route

Comment: `:80` is not a valid path. Path is anything after the hostname and port, eg. `/foo`. `GET :80` is not a valid HTTP request.

Comment: In fact fb adds ":80/" after the domain name which is causing the "error" and I am trying to "repair" this to avoid the error, but I don't know why fb is adding ":80/" even if 80 is the default port number and why I'm still receiving errors while the redirection route works...

Comment: It doesn't matter if :80 is added after the hostname. 80 is the default port for HTTP. Specifying a hostname with or without port 80 results in the same thing.

Comment: Yes I know but look at the error message in the question, it's explicit

Comment: Sure, there is an error, but you are trying to fix it from the wrong side.

Comment: The good route is provided to fb as I don't provide it with ":80/" but after, the request is coming from fb, so don't know what to do...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122808/discussion-between-gerry-and-laurent).

Comment: @Gerry I still have this problem, each share on fb calls :80 url, it's not reaaly a "problem" as the url is found and the share is well done on fb, but as I still receive the message, it's because a call is made and as I can't reproduce this call, I can't solve it, so do you know (maybe) where I can ask/check/or whatever to find a way to soluce this ? Thanks

Comment: @Laurent As I explained before, the only real solution is making sure Facebook does not use an invalid URL to refer to your site.

Comment: Yes, my question (if you have the answer or a way to it) is, I am 100% sure that the url shared on fb is good and without this ":80" part and moreover it occurs on every share, so it's coming from fb, or something inside Symfony router, but I doubt...

Comment: Hello, having the error logs coming from Facebook mobile app. For there no reason FB should call this, it should be reported to them as a bug. instead of calling `domain.com:80/toto` they call `domain.com/:80toto`

Comment: Clearly we don't have to provide additional routes to correct these cases.

Comment: For sure we don't have to provide these routes, but sometimes it's easier to provide route than to wait for a solution of a bug... But it has been solved as fb doesn't call anymore these routes. Thanks